# Allowed to insert into table only once

Tags: php, mysql

I'm able to insert into my table 'submittedresume' only once. I'm trying to develop an apply for job post feature but for some reason, my table only allows for single inserts; even when I am trying to apply for another job post that has a different job_id. I'm constantly getting a database query fail after my first insert.

This is my table.

```
submitted_id (auto increment) | individual_id | resume_id |submitted_status 
1                             |2              | 2         |1
2                             |3              | 3         |1
```

This is my query code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `submittedresume` 
        (`individual_id`, `resume_id`, `submitted_date`, 
         `submitted_status`, `job_post_id`, `application_desc`) "
     . "VALUES ('$Id','$resumeId','$uploadDate','1','$jobId',
                '$content')";

$results = $database->query($sql);
return $results;
```

Comment: Not quite clear on what it is you're asking. Perhaps re-read what you posted and see if it makes sense to you.  Also, maybe it would be helpful to post the table structure so we can check for unique indexes.

Comment: You probably have a unique index/constraint on `job_id`.

Comment: I assume that your table actually has all the fields `individual_id`, `resume_id`, `submitted_date`, `submitted_status`, `job_post_id`, `application_desc` Because you actually said the table only contained `submitted_id (auto increment) | individual_id | resume_id |submitted_status`

Comment: check for errors on the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Hi all thank you for your replies. You guys are right, my problem was due to a variable accidentally set as a unique constraint

Answer (score 0):

```
  Please create database and then create table 
  --------------------------------------------
        #   Name                Type            Collation       Attributes  Null    Default         Extra   
        1   SrNo                double                                      No          None        AUTO_INCREMENT      
        2   submitted_date      date                                        No          None            
        3   resume_id           double                                      No          None            
        4   job_post_id         double                                      No          None            
        5   submitted_status    varchar(30)     latin1_swedish_ci           No          None            
        6   job_description     varchar(200)    latin1_swedish_ci           No          None
```

---

```
  <?php
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_submittedresume`(`SrNo`,`submitted_date`, `resume_id`, `job_post_id`, `submitted_status`, `job_description`)
        VALUES ('',$_POST['txtSubmittedDate'],$_POST['txtResumeId'],$_POST['txtJobPostId'],$_POST['txtSubmittedStatus'],$_POST['txtJobDescription'])");

       ?>
```